# How to get asset from a Cloudflare DDOS protected url?

Tags: flutter, security, dart, cloudflare

I want to get the audio as bytes with Dio http client, so I can play audio from a local file. I was using audioplayers plugin and it was working fine just by giving it a url until we add cloudflare. Now that 5 seconds DDOS protection throws 503 status code.

I wonder if there's a workaround to get this data from a link protected with Cloudflare.

[sample image url](http://img.shannonside.ie/staging/uploads/sites/11/JoeFinneganShow-18-1024x576.jpg)
[sample audio url](https://www.shannonside.ie/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/Charlie-McConalague.mp3)

Answer (score 0):

From Cloudflare official website, [using Cloudflare with your API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API):

> Security Level: Not IUAM The Security level controls Cloudflare's basic protection level  for the URL pattern. When this feature is set to "I'm Under Attack" either in the Cloudflare settings or in a page rule, each visitor is presented with an interstitial page with a 5 second delay before the request is redirected to its destination.

> **We advise specifying this to anything but "I'm Under Attack" so that there is never a delay applied to API requests.**

So you should remove the feature "I'm Under Attack"